# Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false' on open kendo-datepicker for angular in modal dialog

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ng-bootstrap, kendo-datepicker

I'm working on angular 4 app. I have installed angular - 4.0.3, bootstrap - 3.3.7, ng-bootstrap - 1.0.0-alpha.15, @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs - ^1.0.3.

I open modal dialog that have inside kendo-datepicker. When I click on open datepicker icon I have error:

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.`

I tried to add

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewChecked, AfterContentChecked, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: "ac-task-modal",
    templateUrl: "./app/core/modals/task-modal.component.html"
})
export class AddTaskModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewChecked, AfterContentChecked {
    fromDate = new Date();
    dueDate? = new Date();
    taskForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
        public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.buildForm();
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        this.ref.detectChanges();
    }

    ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
        this.ref.detectChanges();
    }

    buildForm() {
        this.taskForm =
            this.formBuilder.group({
                description: this.task.description,
                note: "",
                assignee: new FormControl()
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {

    }
}
```

But it didn't help.
When I insert kendo-datepicker not in modal dialog, it works fine.

Where is the error into kendo-datepicker, ng-bootstrap or angular? And how can I resolve it?

Important note I have theme on my project for bootstrap v3, so I can't update ng-bootstrap to the latest version, because the latest versions for bootstrap v4, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: can you post your ENTIRE ts file code?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Yes, sure, look at it please

Comment: mmm the problem is related to the angular devmode ..which do  adouble check of the variables changes ... i think it is related to yours  fromDate = new Date();
    dueDate? = new Date(); fields ... cause their values changes from when you declare them... do you need them with seconds? ..or try ti investigate on them

Comment: No, i don't need it with seconds, just day, month, year. Very strange, because it works on simple page not in modal dialog.

Comment: just give a try ... try to set with only days and month and year and test it

Comment: if you mean this `new Date(2017, 12, 12)` then I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try upgrading to the latest version of the Kendo UI for Angular DateInputs (currently 1.4.2) - the DatePicker seems to be working as expected in a Bootstrap 4 modal:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Select a date:</p>
            <kendo-datepicker
                [(value)]="value"
            ></kendo-datepicker>
            <p>(use Alt+↓ to open the calendar, ← and →  to navigate, ↑ to increment and ↓ to decrement the value)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/vGreA4KbcyPzC6P7gYXT?p=preview)

Comment: I use UI theme with Bootstrap 3.3.7. Also I use ng-bootstrap plugin to inject modal dialogs everywhere I want. But in your way I need to put html into every component where I need modal dialog.